# MySQL ERROR 1072: States Key doesn't exist, yet it does exist

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-index

Apologies if this is a newbie question, but I have been unable to resolve this problem for some time and am hoping someone with a better understand of MySQL can assist me in deciphering the following problem:
I have two tables that I want to maintain so that users can define their preferences, while an admin can maintain their access rights to those preferences. And I want to make sure that if an admin removes certain rights, that the preferences table gets updated:
The two tables are:

```
main_access
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nav_location | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and

```
main_prefs
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| nav_location | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| user_id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

They both have unique indexes, as I run this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main_access (
    nav_location    integer not null,
    user_id         integer not null,
    unique index uk_access (nav_location, user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main_pref (
    nav_location    integer not null,
    user_id         integer not null,
    unique index uk_pref (nav_location, user_id)
);
```

So, uk_access, and uk_pref with the above tables are being created. Yet, when I run:

```
ALTER TABLE main_pref 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_access1 
FOREIGN KEY(uk_pref) REFERENCES main_access(uk_access) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

I get the "ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'uk_pref' doesn't exist in table" error. Which, to me, makes zero sense to get. I know the key exists, as I also ran the following after creating the tables:

```
ALTER TABLE main_pref ADD UNIQUE INDEX uk_pref (nav_location, user_id);
```

and got a duplicate key warning. I did the same thing with the other table.
I also tried making the unique index name the same for both tables. That is, I made them both `uk_pref`, to no avail. Same error.
I feel like this is a really simple problem that I'm missing, but just haven't been able to see it. I am hoping another set of eyes will point out the mistake I'm making. Any help is much appreciated!
I looked for similar problems, but could not find any on here that addressed the same issue.

EDIT: AJ pointed this out, and I forgot to mention that I tried it:
I also (first) tried bypassing setting unique keys and did the following:

```
ALTER TABLE main_pref 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_access1 
FOREIGN KEY(user_id, nav_location) REFERENCES main_access(user_id, nav_location) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And MySQL just came back a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure you can create a foreign key constraint against an index?  What if you specify the columns in the uk_pref index as a tuple instead of the index name?

Comment: Do you mean why don't I try : ALTER TABLE main_pref ADD CONSTRAINT FK_access1 FOREIGN KEY(user_id, nav_location) REFERENCES main_access(user_id, nav_location) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;? If so, I tried that, and it produces a syntax error. Also, I am pretty sure, but not 100% sure. I think so, based on this thread http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?135,427283,427283#msg-427283

Comment: k - i didn't see in your o.p. that you had tried this approach.

Comment: I didn't mention that. I'll add it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave the columns in the key definitions in the wrong order

```
ALTER TABLE main_pref 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_access1 
FOREIGN KEY(nav_location,user_id) REFERENCES main_access(nav_location,user_id) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This works fine

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16751

The FK columns must be given in the same order as in the key definition in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.  Put another way, a composite indes on `(nav_location,user_id)` cannot be used to satisfy an FK definition on `(user_id,nav_location)` as in your original post.

Comment: I will try this out, thank you! As of right now, that gives error 1005, but that usually means there is some anomaly in my alter table statements.

Comment: I get the same error using sqlfiddle when trying to build my full schema. I will start throwing things out until I get it... how frustrating.

Comment: There were some obvious anomalies that I had to address that I didn't notice before. Thank you very much for the answer. This problem alone has really helped me out with MySQL in general.